# ISRC Code from AVMetadataItem objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller, avasset, avmetadataitem

I want to get the ISRC code for Local itunes songs. I can get the metaData by the following codes:

```
 MPMusicPlayerController *mp= mp = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
  NSURL *assetURL = [mp.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
    NSArray *metadata = [asset commonMetadata];
        for ( AVMetadataItem* item in metadata ) {
            NSString *key = [item commonKey];
            NSString *value = [item stringValue];
            NSLog(@"extra iptions %@",[item extraAttributes]);
            NSLog(@"key = %@, value = %@", key, value);

            NSLog(@"keyspace and Local %@   %@",[item keySpace],[item key]);

        }
```

But I am really wondering about how to get ISRC(International Standard Record Coding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (warning: typed into browser)

```
NSArray *metadata = [asset metadataForFormat:AVMetadataFormatID3Metadata];
if (metadata == nil) {
    NSLog(@"No ID3 metadata for asset: %@", asset);
}
// From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_ID3Constants/Reference/reference.html

NSArray *filteredMetadata = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:metadata withKey:AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyInternationalStandardRecordingCode keySpace:nil];
AVMetadataItem *item = [filteredMetadata firstObject];
if (item != nil) {
    NSLog(@"ISRC: %@", item.stringValue);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No ISRC found for: %@", asset);
}
```

**EDIT:** I should mention, the reason your original code didn't print the value of the ISRC is because the ISRC is not part of the common metadata space, and won't be included in the array returned by `[asset commonMetadata]`. The ISRC key is specific to ID3 metadata, so if your asset does not have ID3 metadata associated with it, you will be unable to retrieve that information.

Comment: Hi indragie Thanks for your answer...Some times output is "No ISRC found"...Some time it prints the website name like "Desinapster.com"..what it means ?

Comment: If it's printing "No ISRC found" that means the ISRC metadata hasn't been set for that asset, and whatever its printing is the value of the ISRC metadata field. You may want to log the `filteredMetadata` array to see if there's somehow more than one metadata item in there, but there shouldn't be.

Comment: Also, you could try passing in `AVMetadataKeySpaceID3` to the keySpace parameter in `AVMetadataItem +metadataItemsFromArray:withKey:keySpace` to see if that somehow changes the filtered results.

Comment: i tried this one also..but still i got Some website name(Desinapster.com) as output...if there is a website name instead of ISRC what i should do ? do i need to display "No ISRC found"  for this output also ?

Comment: In the case where you have a value for the ISRC but it isn't an *actual* ISRC (like a website name, in your case), you would have to use a regular expression (using the `NSRegularExpression` class) to match the correct format of an ISRC code, and if the validation fails you can show that there was no ISRC.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do NSRegularExpression to validate ISRC..?thanks in advance